# What does class specific means mean?

Tags: r, svm

I am going through some worksheets and I have come across a question that has confused me. So the question asks to generate a matrix `x` of size 200 x 2 randomly generated data by the r code
`matrix(rnorm(300*2), ncol=2)`. In the matrix, each 100 entries belong to a class, from 1 to 3. It also asks to define class specific means in variable `z` as `matrix(c(0,0,3,0,3,0),3,2)`. There is a vector `y` with labels 1 to 3. It then asks to assign class specific means to the data points of each class only using `y` and `z`. And I'm a bit confused by the wording. The vector `y` is just (1, 1, 1, 1, ....., 3, 3, 3, 3), with 1, 2 and 3 repeated 100 times. How do I assign class specific means to the data points with just `y` and `z` ?

My end goal is to assign the class specific means to the data points in x and plot x to show if they are linearly separable.

Edit to add: The x matrix is defined by `matrix(rnorm(300*2), ncol=2)`. I have previously put it as `matrix(rnorm(200*2), ncol=2)`

Comment: Does length of `y` is 100 or 300?

Comment: @Park the length of y is 300

Comment: Then `x` has 200 samples. Which class they are in?

Comment: @Park Please check my edited post. I have corrected it. It should say ```matrix(rnorm(300*2), ncol=2)```. I have mistakenly put it as 200 * 2

Answer (score 0):

If `y` is length 100 that indicates groups,

```
x <- matrix(rnorm(300*2), ncol=2)

y <- c(rep(1,100),rep(2,100),rep(3,100))
x <- as.data.frame(x)
x$group <- y
```

## Base `R`

```
z <- aggregate(x[,1:2], list(x$group), mean)
as.matrix(z[,-1])

                V1           V2
[1,]  0.0008374542 -0.154219125
[2,] -0.0902750516 -0.052787157
[3,] -0.0758869275  0.004063367
```

## `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

z <- x %>%
  group_by(group) %>%
  summarize(m1 = mean(V1), 
            m2 = mean(V2)) %>%
  select(-group) %>%
  as.matrix

                m1           m2
[1,]  0.0008374542 -0.154219125
[2,] -0.0902750516 -0.052787157
[3,] -0.0758869275  0.004063367
```

If you want column names of `z` like in your question, add `colnames(z) <- NULL`

Comment: Thank you. But the z matrix has already been defined as ```matrix(c(0,0,3,0,3,0),3,2)```. I don't think the 3 could be overwritten

Comment: @ambrosianium May I ask `z`'s role in your question?

Comment: Here's the part of the question that might answer you
```To make these 300 entries distinctive and
divide the data into 3 different classes, lets define class specific means in variable z as
”matrix(c(0,0,3,0,3,0),3,2)”. Also, generate a response vector y of size N that contains
labels (1 to 3) for the data in x. Using z and y, assign class specific means to data
points of each class and this operation will change the entries of the matrix x and divide
it into three classes.```

Comment: @ambrosianium What I understand is, make as form of `z`, matrix(3,2)...